# Android Studio- Button/ImageButton click Intent does not go to Listview layout. Error- "App Has Stopped"

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new in Android. My problem is, Button/ImageButton click Intent does not go to Listview layout. Error- "App Has Stopped"
It works for other layout. 
If I open list View seperately, data shows.

My Codes:

1- MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

```
private ImageButton imageButton1,imageButton2;
private Intent intent;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageButton1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonid1);
    imageButton2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonid2);



    imageButton1.setOnClickListener(this);
    imageButton2.setOnClickListener(this);

}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId()){

        case R.id.buttonid1:
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListActivity01.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;

        case R.id.buttonid2:
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ListActivity02.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;

    }


}
```

}

2-   ListActivity01.java

public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private ListView listView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewid);

    String[] bddist = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.bdDistricts);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ListActivity.this,R.layout.listviewmid,R.id.txtviewmidid,bddist);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);


    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            int itemposition = position;

            Intent intent = new Intent(ListActivity.this,ChildActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("name", itemposition);
            startActivity(intent);


        }

    });

}
```

Comment: The “App Has Stopped” message is intended for non-programmers. What you are interested in (and we if you want help in case you don't understand it) is an exception printed in the LogCat window (should be bottom left or `Alt+6`). Hint: you can set the level to `Error` if there are too much unrelated logs

Comment: Post the log please

Comment: hi, Thanks a lot. My purpose is simple. 2 button in main. COUNTRIES, FLOWERS. when I click COUNTRIES buton, countries list will be shown in LISTVIEW. same as flowers. but, when I click buttons, listview dont show.

Comment: And Log Cat Shows this error-

/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module